Python and selenium problems with combobox
I have a problem trying to send a click on a drop-down item, the item must be previously selected and then repeat the selection.
When selecting the item its class is z-comboitem z-comboitem-selected, I have obtained its ID and verified the value is correct.
Using the following code I get the id
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'zk_comp_402-btn'))).click()
time.sleep(0.5)
# wait
contenedor_diagnostico = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "zk_comp_402-cave")))
# Find the selected item within the contenedor_diagnostico
elemento_seleccionado_diag = contenedor_diagnostico.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".z-comboitem-selected")
# Get the ID of the selected item
captura_id_diagnostico = elemento_seleccionado_diag.get_attribute("id")

but when sending a click on the button that displays the list and then trying to send a click to the id corresponding to "z-comboitem z-comboitem-selected" it does not do it
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'zk_comp_402-btn'))).click()
time.sleep(0.5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, captura_id_diagnostico))).click()

I add the html of the sector in question
<div id="zk_comp_402-pp" class="z-combobox-popup z-combobox-open z-combobox-shadow" style="width: auto; z-index: 1800; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 1506.65px; left: 372.217px;" tabindex="-1">
<ul id="zk_comp_402-cave" class="z-combobox-content" style="height: auto; width: auto;">
<li id="zk_comp_725" class="z-comboitem z-comboitem-selected">
<span class="z-comboitem-image"></span>
<span class="z-comboitem-text">INSUFICIENCIA&nbsp;CARDIACA,&nbsp;NO&nbsp;ESPECIFICADA</span>
</li>
<li id="zk_comp_726" class="z-comboitem">
<span class="z-comboitem-image"></span>
<span class="z-comboitem-text">
ACCIDENTE&nbsp;&nbsp;VASCULAR&nbsp;ENCEFALICO&nbsp;AGUDO,&nbsp;NO&nbsp;ESPECIFICADO&nbsp;COMO&nbsp;HEMORRAGICO&nbsp;O&nbsp;ISQUEMICO
</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

How to find a solution to the problem?
I don't have much experience using python and selenium.
